# storing info in dynamic array? using id# as variable name

Tags: php, dynamic-arrays

This probably seems pretty simple but here goes.
I'm working on simple tracking of parts for a product.

each product has a list of parts and quantities to build it.
there are also options and quantities,

I was using $$partid = $qty or $$optionid = $qty.
but, sometimes the id numbers would match.

I end up with needing 5 partid_99 (as $$partid) instead of 4 partid_99 and 1 optionid_99

Can I split them up (coming out of a SELECT query w/ WHILE) something like...
*$SinglePart[$partid] = $qty; (4)
$SingleOption[$partid] = $qty; (1)*

**Playing with it...**

`while ($crr = mysql_fetch_array($reGetAll)) {
        $optionid = $crr["optionid"];
        $SingleOption[$optionid] = $crr["quantity"];
    }

    echo "Option:379= ".$SingleOption["379"]."<br>";
    echo $SingleOption[379]."<br>"; 
    var_dump($SingleOption);`

**Gives me...**

Option:379=

array(0) { }

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What does a var_dump($curr); print?

Comment: it prints "bool(false) "

Comment: the solution seems top be to change $99 to $opt-99 if an option and simply str_replace("opt-", "", $optionid

Comment: This means you have an error in your query or no matches are found, can you please post your query as well?

Comment: $GetAll = "SELECT optionid, quantity FROM dune_dune.order_options WHERE orderid = '325245'";

Comment: Sorry my bad, it should be var_dump($crr); what does it print?